# How to Mock another method of same class we are testing in c# without dependency injection

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, automation, moq

I am facing one scenario where I need to mock another method of the same class in c#. But I am facing issue to mock another method and the same I am sharing below.

```
 Interface --> 

  public interface IFetch
  {
     string GetColorCodes();

     string FetchData();

  }

  Class-->
 public class Fetch : IFetch 
 {

    public Fetch()
    {
     //I dont have any dependency injection
    }

   public string GetColorCodes() {
    return "Yellow";
   }

   public string FetchData(){
   string  color= GetColorCodes();
   return color;
 }
```

Now, while creating a unit test for testing FetchData() method I don't want it should internally call GetColorCodes() method and returns "Yellow". I want to return some other color like "Red".
Since there is no dependency and method is in the same class I am not able to find out the way. If anyone has an idea please share with this sample code

```
[TestFixture]
class FetchTest 
{
   [Test]
   public void FetchDataTest()
  {
   Fetch obj=new Fetch();
   string color= obj.FetchData();
  Assert.IsEquals(color,"Red")
  }

}

I want to mock the GetColorCodes() method from the test to Return Red color.
```

Comment: This is the problem with mocking: _You need to test your code.  You decide to use mocking.  Now you have two problems._

Comment: This is possible with unconstrained isolation frameworks such as TypeMock or JustMock (both are paid), and MS Fakes. What isolating framework do you use?

Comment: This appears to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). The question in its current state is also incomplete and therefore unclear. Read [ask] and then edit the question to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that can be used to reproduce the problem, allowing a better understanding of what is actually being asked.

Comment: Why you need to test for "Red" color if original method always returns "Yellow"?

Answer (score 3):

If you have no problems with making `GetColorCodes()` virtual then you can use the [Extract and Override](http://taswar.zeytinsoft.com/extract-and-override-refactoring-technique/) test pattern. In your test, new up FetchStub with the mock value you wish to use and call your method under test FetchData from the same instance:

```
public class FetchStub : Fetch
{
    private readonly string _colorCode;
    public FetchStub(string colorCode)
    {
        _colorCode = colorCode;     
    }

    public override string GetColorCodes()
    {
        return _colorCode;
    }
}


public class Fetch
{

    public Fetch()
    {
        //I dont have any dependency injection
    }

    public virtual string GetColorCodes()
    {
        return "Yellow";
    }

    public string FetchData()
    {
        string color = GetColorCodes();
        return color;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

FetchData method doesn't have any dependencies here. You can't mock part of class to test another part of class. You need to introduce some dependency here, e.g. like this:

```
   public interface IColorProvider
   {
       string GetColor();
   }

   public class DefaultColorProvider : IColorProvider
   {
       public string GetColor => "Yellow";
   }

    public class Fetch : IFetch 
    {
        private readonly IColorProvider _colorProvider;
        public Fetch(IColorProvider colorProvider)
        {
          _colorProvider = colorProvider
        }

        public string FetchData(){
        string  color= _colorProvider.GetColor()
        return color;
    }
```

In this case - you have clear dependency and you can mock behavior of IColorProvider and test behavior of FetchData.

UPDATE: 
You can do something like this:

```
    public class Fetch : IFetch 
    {
        private readonly IColorProvider _colorProvider;
        public Fetch(IColorProvider colorProvider)
        {
          _colorProvider = colorProvider
        }

        public string GetColorCodes() {
             return _colorProvider.GetColor();
        }

        public string FetchData(){
        string  color= GetColorCodes();
        return color;
    }
```

So changes in the class will be very small but it will give you ability to test this.

Comment: The  problem is this is an existing class and it has several method and I cannot create an interface for GetColor() method

Comment: You can try to do something with your existing code using TypeMock Isolator which has a lot of ways to mock methods even instance methods - but I'm not sure that this is good practice.